# How do I get unique values in a Pandas DataFrame that match criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
df_amazon = pd.DataFrame ({
    'order_no':[1, 2, 3],
    'category':['Books', 'Toys', 'Books'],
    'seller':['Amazon.com', 'AZ Toys', 'amazon'] })
```

I want to obtain all of the unique values in the seller column if they relate to Amazon.

In SQL, there is a LIKE Keyword. For example:

```
SELECT seller FROM df_amazon WHERE LOWER(seller) LIKE 'amazon%'
```

The code above will return all records where the lowercase text in the seller column starts with 'amazon'.

**Is there something similar in Pandas?**

I've tried the following:

```
df_amazon.loc[df_amazon.seller.str.contains('amazon')]
```

but this matches strictly on the third row and leaves out the first row with 'Amazon.com'.

I then tried the following:

```
df_amazon.loc[df_amazon.seller.str.lower().contains('amazon')]
```

but this returns an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'

**I would like to quickly obtain all unique values where the seller is Amazon.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `case=False` parameter in [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
df_amazon.loc[df_amazon.seller.str.contains('amazon', case=False), 'seller'].unique()
```

Your second solution is modified by another `str`:

```
df_amazon.loc[df_amazon.seller.str.lower().str.contains('amazon'), 'seller'].unique()
```

Comment: probably throw in `seller` in the columns section of `loc`, to select only the seller column; it should match the OP's requirement

Comment: If I wanted to get all of the unique values, what would I use because I get an error when I put that logic into df_amazon.seller.unique(): 

`df_amazon.seller.unique( df_amazon.loc[df_amazon.seller.str.contains('amazon', case = False)] )`

returns TypeError: unique() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 3):

You have to have one more `.str`:

```
df_amazon.loc[df_amazon.seller.str.lower().str.contains('amazon')]
```

Or use `case=False`:

```
df_amazon.loc[df_amazon.seller.str.contains('amazon', case=False)]
```

Or specify the flags:

```
import re
df_amazon.loc[df_amazon.seller.str.lower().str.contains('amazon',  flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```